# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log (stats.boxcox)

Tags: python, scipy, divide-by-zero

I am getting the `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` error when I tried to run `stats.boxcox(list)`.

The list contained no zero values. I have refers to some others posts saying that we can ignore the error using `np.errstate()`.

But, in my case, I don't think it is proper as the value return by `stats.boxcox()` are meaningless (all constant, see below).

```
array([ 0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,
    0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,
    0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,  0.11472901,
    0.11472901,  0.11472901,  ... ... ]
```

The details of the error are as follow:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/morestats.py:591: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
llf -= N / 2.0 * np.log(np.sum((y - y_mean)**2. / N, axis=0))
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:2063: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
w = xb - ((xb - xc) * tmp2 - (xb - xa) * tmp1) / denomenter code here
```

Comment: You may want  to be more specific here. What version of `scipy` are you using?  Does this also happen if you use only the first 10 values of `list`? If so, can you show us the values, so we can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @cel I am using scipy version 0.15.1. The list contained of 494 numbers. The problems does not occur if I randomly removed 2 numbers.

Comment: You are passing in an ndarray, not a list, right?

Comment: Yes. I am using nparray. I changed to to list but I still get the same error.

Comment: As @FrancoPiccolo pointed out, you are probably experiencing the error reported in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6873.  This been fixed in the development branch of scipy.  The fix will be in the next release (scipy 1.3).

Answer (score 0):

I followed a suggestion on this Github thread and worked for me:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6873

The suggestion is to use `stats.boxcox_normmax(array)` to get the ideal lambda and then do the `boxcox` transformation.

```
boxcox_lambda = boxcox_normmax(array, brack=(-1.9, 2.0),  method='mle')
transformed_array = boxcox(array, boxcox_lambda)
```